# Cypress: cannot find button in toolbar

Tags: cypress

I just started playing with `cypress` and I am trying to write down some tests in my sandbox application. In my first test user should click on a 'button' to make the toolbar to appear, then click on a button to activate the feature, then click a couple of times on a `leaflet` map to draw a line.

As you can see: click on 'Tools', then click on 'draw route' button and then click on map to draw.

[image]

This dummy app is wrapped inside a web component, here is the code:

[image]

And here is my test code:

```
describe('Draw geometries on map', ()=>{
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('http://192.168.49.2:30000/scouter/');
  })

  ...

  it('can draw after clicking draw button', ()=>{
    cy.get('scouter-web').shadow().find('.scouter-tools-main-button').click()
    cy.get('scouter-web').shadow().find('draw route').click()
    console.log('new cy')
    cy.get('scouter-web').shadow().get('scouter-web').shadow().find('#map')
    .click(400, 400)
    .click(400, 600)
    .click(500, 600)
  })
});
```

Problem is I, after clicking 'Tools', I can't 'find' the 'draw route' button. What am I missing? The whole stuff can be found [here](https://github.com/fpezzati/movona/tree/feature/tryin_cypress), subproject is `scouter-web`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `shadow()` repeatedly, you can mention `includeShadowDom: true` once in your `cypress.json` file.

With `find` you can just use selector but I think you are using text. If you just want to use text, you can use contains.

```js
cy.contains('draw route').click()
```

And if your application is throwing `Uncaught Exceptions` you can add to your `cypress/support/index.js` to globally turn off all uncaught exception handling. But a fair bit of warning, do this only when you are sure that the exceptions generated can be ignored.

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  // returning false here prevents Cypress from
  // failing the test
  return false
})
```